# android providing different drawable resources for orientations

Tags: android

I would like to provide different drawable resources for different orientations.  What is the proper folder name to provide a landscape and portrait version of a drawable? I looked through the android documentation and haven't seen anything like `drawable-hdpi-land` or `drawable-hdpi-port`.  Are these the proper names?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

it's 
drawable-land-hdpi etc, 
see the documentation for the full order:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/index.html

Comment: [Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#table2) you can find more details.